# MongoDB - 100% CPU - recovering shard (after killing updates)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Can a recovering shard (as shown below) drive CPU to 100% for hours and hours?
I have killed all the queries and updates (based on db.currentOp()) and stopped the flow of new data, but the CPU stays at 100%.

I can run little queries, but deleting 200 rows (via an index) runs for hours.
Inserts are getting backed up and not performing timely.  We have a large collection (almost 200 GB) with about 5 indexes.

Can the server be doing internal clean-up that runs the CPU so high that our normal flow of data bogs down?

[image]
(running cloud/Atlas)

In the db.currentOps(), I see quite a few that look like the json below; these don't seem to represent any queries, inserts, updates, or deletes that we are running or started.

```
{
    "type": "op",
    "host": "atlas-10ydpn-shard-00-04.otwxp.mongodb.net:27017",
    "desc": "conn1280774",
    "connectionId": 1280774,
    "client": "54.221.39.10:59692",
    "clientMetadata": {
        "driver": {
            "name": "PyMongo",
            "version": "3.11.0"
        },
        "os": {
            "type": "Linux",
            "name": "Linux",
            "architecture": "x86_64",
            "version": "4.14.193-110.317.amzn2.x86_64"
        },
        "platform": "CPython 3.7.9.final.0"
    },
    "active": true,
    "currentOpTime": "2020-10-22T12:52:12.100+0000",
    "effectiveUsers": [
        {
            "user": "pythonapp",
            "db": "admin"
        }
    ],
    "opid": 20478470,
    "lsid": {
        "id": "059e860217054269a3f30c93a7b9c9cb",
        "uid": null
    },
    "secs_running": 2370,
    "microsecs_running": 2370403369,
    "op": "command",
    "ns": "relatixtd.$cmd",
    "command": {
        "update": "ProdPolygonIOQuotes",
        "ordered": true,
        "writeConcern": {
            "w": "majority"
        },
        "lsid": {
            "id": "059e860217054269a3f30c93a7b9c9cb"
        },
        "txnNumber": 1,
        "$clusterTime": {
            "clusterTime": null,
            "signature": {
                "hash": null,
                "keyId": 6857244042040705026
            }
        },
        "$db": "relatixtd"
    },
    "numYields": 1,
    "waitingForLatch": {
        "timestamp": null,
        "captureName": "ReplicationCoordinatorImpl::_mutex"
    },
    "locks": {},
    "waitingForLock": false,
    "lockStats": {
        "ParallelBatchWriterMode": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 4
            }
        },
        "ReplicationStateTransition": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "w": 6
            }
        },
        "Global": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 2,
                "w": 3
            }
        },
        "Database": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 1,
                "w": 3
            }
        },
        "Collection": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 1,
                "w": 3
            }
        },
        "Mutex": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 4
            }
        }
    },
    "waitingForFlowControl": false,
    "flowControlStats": {
        "acquireCount": 2,
        "timeAcquiringMicros": 1
    }
},
```